# C++ template classes including each other

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I'm trying to create a template linked list code by my own (to learn C++), but I'm stuck at one thing. The simplified version of the code is down below:

LinkedList.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    // ...

    void EditNode(Node<T> node)
    {
        // ... do something with the node. That's why I included "Node.h" file in the "LinkedList.h" file
    }

    // ...
};
```

Node.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "LinkedList.h"

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        m_List = list;
        // ... call some methods inside of list. That's why I included the "LinkedList.h" file in the "Node.h" file
    }

private:
    LinkedList<T> m_List;
    // ...
};
```

The errors I'm getting are:
`syntax error: identifier 'LinkedList'` -> This points the constructor of the Node.h file
`m_List: identifier not found` -> This is being shown for every m_List variable inside of the Node.h file

I'm guessing this is because 2 template classes are trying to include each other, but I'm not sure. What's the problem here?

Comment: You can forward declare a class template, just like you can a regular class or struct.

Comment: One of the types is seen first by the compiler, template or not. At that point the compiler doesn't know about the other one. A node object owning a `LinkedList` object is highly unusual. Usually a linked list is made of nodes but if the linked list doesn't own any nodes, you could get away with forward declating the `Node` template in `LinkedList.h` and define the `EditNode` function after the include which comes after the declaration of `Node`.

Comment: @PaulSanders @fabian If I forward declare the classes, how can I use the variables and methods inside them? For example; my `EditNode` method uses the parameter to edit something inside of the parameter. So, my LinkedList.h file must see the inside of the Node.h file. So, I guess, I need to implement it?

Comment: Wait, it worked, but how? How `LinkedList.h` file can see the inside of `Node.h` file without including? Is that how forward declaration works? I thought, forward declarations are just the placeholders for a compiler and when a code needs to be compiled, the compiler changes the include order depending on the declarations. I'm a bit confused

Comment: To call methods on `Node<T>` a forward declaration isn't enough. You need to use `template<typename T> class LinkedList { void EditNode(Node<T> node); } #include "Node.h" template<typename T> void linkedList<T> EditNode(Node<T> node) { ... }` so that when you include `Node.h` the `LinkedList` type is complete and then `Node` is fully declared before the actual `LinkedList` functions use it. Similar in Node.h, the `#pragma once` prevents that from being an infinite recursion.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I cannot separate template classes. There are some ways, but they're not suggested somehow

Comment: The change just reorders where you declare classes, include the other file and define the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your functions outside of the class definitions, so that all of the class definitions are in scope.  Here's an example of what this might look like:

```
template<typename T> class Node;

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    // ...

    void EditNode(Node<T> node);

    // ...
};

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(LinkedList<T> list);

private:
    LinkedList<T> m_List;
    // ...
};

template<typename T> void
LinkedList<T>::EditNode(Node<T> node)
{
// ... do something with the node. That's why I included "Node.h" file in the "LinkedList.h" file
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(LinkedList<T> list)
{
m_List = list;
// ... call some methods inside of list. That's why I included the "LinkedList.h" file in the "Node.h" file
}
```